# Swipe up view on SwiftUI to mimic Instagrams Share Post view

Tags: swift, swiftui

Does anyone know what this particular view is called in SwiftUI where you have a swipe up overlay and then when swipe down, it goes away completely.

Example:

[image]

Comment: The closest thing is a sheet you can find it as a view modifier

Comment: Thanks @loremipsum, I didn't even know about sheets, so this is super helpful!

Comment: Are sheets inner scrollable by any chance? Where they are set as a certain size, so users can scroll inside them, but drag them up and make the view larger?

Comment: They are called presentation detents and of course a scroll view